# How could I make the Edit button work from a modal?

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, modal-dialog

How could I make my edit button work from modal to make and update to the database.

My Modal: (body only)

```
  <div class="modal-body">
      <form class="form" id="employee_update" method="post" action="">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <label>First Name</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <input class="text" type="text" id="first_name" placeholder="{{employee.first_name}}">
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <label>Middle Name</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <input class="text" type="text" id="Middle_name" placeholder="{{employee.middle_name}}">
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <label>Last Name</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <input class="text" type="text" id="last_name" placeholder="{{employee.last_name}}">
              </div>
          </div>
      </form>

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" id="emp_update" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: green">Edit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

> JS(Tried but it wont work)

```
                    <script>
                        $("#emp_update").click( function() {
                        $('#employee_update').submit();
                    });

                    </script>
```

For now after this is my views.py since im still working on that button.

```
def employee_update(request):
return redirect(request, 'index.html')
```

Comment: You should place `{% csrf_token %}` tag inside your HTML form.

Comment: `<form class="form" id="employee_update" method="post" action="{% url name_of_url employee.id %}">` and pass the id in URL `<int:emp_id>`